# Choosing groups of 3 from 3n

Tags: combinatorics

We have $n$ student.
Each student has two parents.

I would like to order the $3n$ people in a row where each family sits together.
The solution is:
$$n! * (3!)^n$$
I understand where this comes from. We treat each family as one object and then order the inside of the family.
I tried something else, and I would like to know where I'm wrong and why.

I tried to choose each time $3$ people(a family) out of $3n-3i$, Like this:
$$\prod_{i=0}^n \binom{3n-3i}{3}$$
Why is this wrong?

Comment: Big number, right? The first factor (for $i=0$) allready gives you the total number of triples among $3n$ persons. Not every triple is a family though.

Comment: @drhab But if I choose 3 out of 3n, that's one family, then the second family by choosing 3 out of 3n-3 and place near the first by multiplying them, and so on.. what's wrong with that logic?

Comment: There are $n$ families, so by choosing a family you only have $n$ options. Not $\binom{3n}3$. If you mean "choosing places" for one family then you must consider the fact that they must sit together.

Comment: @drhab Yep, you're right. Thanks.